# Synchronizing multi-select ListBox with MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, multi-select, virtualizingstackpanel

I have two views of some data: a list view (a `ListBox` now, but I've been meaning to switch to `ListView`) and a fancy graphical representation on a map. In either view the user can click an object and it will be selected in both views. Multiselect is also possible, so each `ViewModel` instance has its own `IsSelected` property.

Currently I'm binding `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` to `ViewModel.IsSelected`, but this only works properly if the `ListBox` is NOT virtualizing ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097999/wpf-binding-to-listboxitem-isselected-doesnt-work-for-off-screen-items)). Unfortunately, disabling virtualization hurts performance and my app has become too slow.

So I have to enable virtualization again. In order to maintain the `ViewModel.IsSelected` property of off-screen items, I noticed that `ListBox` and `ListView` have a `SelectionChanged` event that I can (presumably) use to propagate the selection state from the `ListBox/ListView` to the `ViewModel`.

My question is, how do I propagate selection state in the reverse direction? The `SelectedItems` property of `ListBox/ListView` is read-only! Suppose the user clicks an item in the graphical representation, but it is off-screen w.r.t. the list. If I just set `ViewModel.IsSelected` then the `ListBox/ListView` will be unaware of the new selection, and as a consequence it will fail to *deselect* that item if the user clicks a different item in the list. I could call `ListBox.ScrollIntoView` from the `ViewModel`, but there are a couple of problems:

- In my UI it's actually possible to select two items with one click if they are in the same location graphically, although they may be located in completely different locations in the `ListBox/ListView`.
- It breaks ViewModel isolation (my ViewModel is totally unaware of WPF and I'd like to keep it that way.)

So, my dear WPF experts, any thoughts?

EDIT: I ended up switching to an Infragistics control and using an ugly and rather slow solution. The point is, I no longer need an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind to SelectedItems from DataGrid or ListBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880589/bind-to-selecteditems-from-datagrid-or-listbox-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can create a [Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff726531%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx) that synchronizes `ListBox.SelectedItems` with a collection in your ViewModel:

```
public class MultiSelectionBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        if (SelectedItems != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public IList SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(MultiSelectionBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, SelectedItemsChanged));

    private static void SelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = o as MultiSelectionBehavior;
        if (behavior == null)
            return;

        var oldValue = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        var newValue = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (oldValue != null)
        {
            oldValue.CollectionChanged -= behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= behavior.ListBoxSelectionChanged;
        }
        if (newValue != null)
        {
            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)newValue)
            {
                behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }

            behavior.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += behavior.ListBoxSelectionChanged;
            newValue.CollectionChanged += behavior.SourceCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private bool _isUpdatingTarget;
    private bool _isUpdatingSource;

    void SourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isUpdatingSource)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isUpdatingTarget = true;

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
                }
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }

            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isUpdatingTarget = false;
        }
    }

    private void ListBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isUpdatingTarget)
            return;

        var selectedItems = this.SelectedItems;
        if (selectedItems == null)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isUpdatingSource = true;

            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                selectedItems.Remove(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
            {
                selectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _isUpdatingSource = false;
        }
    }

}
```

This behavior can be used as shown below:

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                 SelectionMode="Extended">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:MultiSelectionBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ListBox>
```

(note that the `SelectedItems` collection in your ViewModel has to be initialized; the behavior won't set it, it will only change its content)

Comment: To make this work, it should be noted that you have to track down a copy of System.Windows.Interactivity.dll (it's in the Expression Blend SDK) and you have to define the "i:" prefix in the XAML root element, as xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"... you also have to define xmlns:local to point to the namespace that contains MultiSelectionBehavior.

Comment: Oddly enough, although this class is derived from Behavior<ListBox>, I was able to attach it to a ListView without modification! It turns out that a ListView is derived from ListBox.

Comment: [PRISM MVVM Reference Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405492%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) uses this approach too. It has a behaviour called SynchronizeSelectedItems, used in Prism4\MVVM RI\MVVM.Client\Views\MultipleSelectionView.xaml, which synchronizes checked items with the ViewModel property named Selections

Comment: Got it working in my app. The trick: I had to use an `ObservableCollection` for the `SelectedItems` in my view model, otherwise it kept having a count of 0.

Comment: Had to add 'if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset) AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();' into SourceCollectionChanged() method if you are clearing the target collection programatically.

Comment: doesn't work, it loads correctly with all already selected items right, but once I add or remove a selection the target collection ends up null

Comment: Works but throws a design time NullRef Exception in SelectedItemsChanged for me. All my properties are initialized. I had to add Null checks for `behavior.AssociatedObject ` to fix it

Comment: I'm getting loads of InvalidCastExceptions from this code, happening so often, it actually slowed down the code significantly - in the `ListBoxSelectionChanged` handler. I believe it's because my DataGrid has combo boxes inside cells (judging by the values when exceptions are happening) and it's going ballistic dealing with these. I had to write an exception handler to catch the bogus errors to do nothing but it happens so often, it practically kills the grid