# How to bind many groups of checkboxes in mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I have three ListBoxes in my view, each ListBox's DataTemplate contains a checkbox, user could select any selections, after complete selecting and click a button, I need to collect all the checkboxes are checked by user in each ListBox. How to do it with bind two way?

Comment: I'm failing to see your problem here... What exactly did you find challenging?

Comment: two way binding on multiple selection is not supported by default, you will need custom behavior. Like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088595/synchronizing-multi-select-listbox-with-mvvm